# Probability of non-negative matrix relaxation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $M\in\Bbb\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$, take $\mathscr{M}[M]=\{Q\in R_{\geq0}^{n\times n}:Q[ij]>0\iff M[ij]=1\}$.

Does $$\mathcal{P}_{n\rightarrow\infty,Q\in\mathscr{M}[M],M\in\Bbb\{0,1\}^{n\times n},\mathsf{rank}(M)=r}\Big(\mathsf{rank}(Q)=r\Big)\rightarrow1$$ hold truth when $r>f(n)\in\Bbb N$ where $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow\Bbb N$ is some choice of function characterizing minimum ranks necessary to make above statement in truth?

Comment: I'm assuming the entries are iid and your probability measure on $\mathbb R_+$ is equivalent to Lebesgue measure. Then this follows from the result that $M$ has full rank with prob almost $1$, and of course generic real positive entries won't destroy this property. See http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0461

Comment: Thank you for comment. I want to see if it holds for singular matrices as well which is why I mentioned $\mathsf{rank}(M)=\mathsf{rank}(Q)$. Updated question. Hopefully made this point clear. Applicability to Singular cases also follows from results in paper?

Comment: This depends on what $r$ is. If $r=1$ for example, then typically $Q$ will have much bigger rank.

Comment: That would be very right. Is there minimum $r$ beyond which result holds?